# Why Use a Biased Resistor?

Tags: resistors, bias

As a school project I was wiring up an IR LED in series with a biasing resist. I was using a breadboard and a vex cortex controller. I understand that a resistor is important because it prevents the LED from receiving to much current and burning out, but why do they use a biased resistor rather than a normal resistor?

Comment: I think you mean bias resistor, which is just a normal resistor. It is simply being used to 'bias' the diode, i.e. set its operating conditions

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. You may be confusing what a resistor is used for, which can be many things in addition to current limiting. Bias and gate dampening and snubbers are just a few.

Comment: it's not surprising they are biased, I mourn the loss of objective resistance. stupid big bang letting matter beat anti-matter....

Answer (score 2):

It's not a "biased resistor", it's a "bias resistor".

This isn't a special kind of resistor. It's any resistor you use to provide a bias or set the bias (operating point) on some other device.

Comment: I think OP is confused by the term 'bias'. It is abstract to the OP.